# Skobbler maps - Failed to calculate route

Tags: ios, objective-c, skmaps

I'm having this strange error when trying to calculate route.
It only happens **first time** app is opened.
After I close an app, and start it again, it works as intended with doing exactly the same thing.

I get Route calculation failed with SKRoutingErrorCodeInvalidStartCoordinate - 681

But it cannot be. 
I checked my logs, and both coordinates are valid, and I use the same ones when I close an app and open it again.

Coordinates are:

```
Start: "longitude":42.360481,"latitude":-71.059570
End: "longitude":40.730598,"latitude":-73.986580
```

Is this a known Issue?

Answer (score 1):

Just tested with the vanilla demo project (cleaned up simulator):

```
        SKRouteSettings* route = [[SKRouteSettings alloc]init];
        route.startCoordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(42.360481,-71.059570);
        route.destinationCoordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.730598,-73.986580);
```

And got a valid route from the first request (see image) 
Could you add your route calculation code snippet to the bug description?

[image]